# When JavaScript updates an input value, AngularJS filtering doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, updates

I'm trying to do some stuffs with Angular from a few days and I'm stucked with an update problem.

This is part of my HTML page :

```
<div ng-app="monApp" ng-controller="monControleur">
Date de début : <input type="text" ng-model="date_deb" placeholder="JJ/MM/AAAA" value="" name="date_d" id="champ_date_deb" size="12" maxlength="10">&nbsp;<span id="calendarMainDeb"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    calInit("calendarMainDeb", "Calendrier Deb", "champ_date_deb", "jsCalendar", "day", "selectedDay","calendarWrap1");
//]]>
</script>
<table border='1'>
<tr data-ng-repeat="evenement in mydata | entre_deux_dates:date_deb:date_fin ">
....
```

When I input a new date_deb with the keyboard, displayed values are filtered with Angular. On the contrary, **if a use a JS calendar to set the date_deb value, it sets the value but no filtering is realized unless giving focus in JS and pressing "space".**

Here is the last part of the JS which updates the date value :

```
field.value = dateArr[0]+'/'+dateArr[1]+'/'+dateArr[2];
field.focus();
```

**What can I do to dynamically update the filtered values right after a date is picked in the calendar ?** I wouldn't like the user to have to press "space" after each selection ...

I have tried a lot of solutions in angular (ng-model-options, etc.) and in JS but none worked.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers.
However, I didn't make it work.
My line with 'field.value' is in a JS function. I tried both your solutions by inserting the code in the JS function but no change.
Do I have to put your code in another place, directly in the .js ? If it is the case, the local variables won't be declared anymore.
I'm a bit confused ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke a digest cycle:

```
 $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
         field.value = dateArr[0]+'/'+dateArr[1]+'/'+dateArr[2]; 
         field.focus();
});
```

That is because angular works by dirty checking - in each digest cycle (apply means run a digest for the root scope), all watchers in the scope hierarchy are checked for changes, and updates occur as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your answer in $timeout, as $timeout runs the digest cycle as well as it saves from the error "$apply alreay running".

```
$timeout(function() {
     field.value = dateArr[0]+'/'+dateArr[1]+'/'+dateArr[2]; 
  });
```